# Playing react native Video inside flatlist item stuck UI & crash some time

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-video, flatlist

I have image & Video files, In react native used flatlist and depending on file Type used Image view or react-native-video & now the multiple video starts playing when render flatlist for the first time and the app UI stuck very much & then app crash sometime ..Please help what to do & how to minimize it ...dont find any reason why this gets happening...

Comment: You need to play only one video that is currently visible on the screen. all others should pause.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that's to much of rendering for a device. You should just play the currently visible videos on the screen.

This might give you an idea or almost a full solution:

You can do it with the `onViewableItemsChanged` prop of FlatList. I don't know how to handle react-native-video, haven't worked with it so far.
But you have to detect the viewable items first by using the first code below and play the video elements like in the second code section. I added the isPlaying as a state variable and linked it in Video element as a prop to set the video playing. I don't know if the prop within react-native-video is called `isPlaying`, but there is surely a prop to set whether video is paused or playing, just find it and rename the isPlaying prop accordingly to get it work.

This code will put all your FlatList items visible on the screen into the Viewable[] array:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [Viewable, SetViewable] = React.useState([]);
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  const onViewRef = React.useRef((viewableItems) => {
    let Check = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < viewableItems.viewableItems.length; i++) {
      Check.push(viewableItems.viewableItems[i].item);
    }
    SetViewable(Check);
  });

  const viewConfigRef = React.useRef({ viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 80 });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={Videos}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item._id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <VideoPlayer {...item} viewable={Viewable} />}
        ref={ref}
        onViewableItemsChanged={onViewRef.current}
        viewabilityConfig={viewConfigRef.current}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

And this one will 'watch' the Viewable array and will do the required changes if the Video element is visible on the screen.

```js
export default function VideoPlayer({ viewable, _id, source }) {
  const video = React.useRef(null);
  const [isPlaying, setPlaying] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (viewable) {
      if (viewable.length) {
        if (viewable[0]._id === _id) {
          setPlaying(true);
        } else {
          setPlaying(false);
        }
      } else {
        setPlaying(false);
      }
    } else {
      setPlaying(false);
    }
  }, [viewable]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Video isPlaying={isPlaying}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sir what is "_id" here? is it the contain of item? (i.e item._id exist) please help sir ...??

Comment: Every FlatList element must have an unique key. In this case => `keyExtractor={(item) => item._id.toString()}`. It's basically the _id attribute of the object in each of your data. Using the code that I provided your data array must look like this: [{_id:1, uri:"https...", type:'video'},{_id:1, uri:"https...", type:'video'},{_id:1, uri:"https...", type:'video'}].

Comment: Sir , i did it the video plays only in View port but still there is a UI stuck problem due to video instance ....what to do for it sir ?

Comment: How many videos / items are we speaking of here? You definitely load the data (into the data={} prop) step by step. I think 3-4 items should be fine speaking of videos / images. In the first state your data={} should contain up to 3-4 items and you have to use the `onEndReached` prop of the Flatlist.  It's an event that fires if the end of the Flatlist is reached (makes sense right?). Now you have to add the next items into data (e.g. data={myStateData} onEndReached={() => {setMyStateData([...myStateData, ...newData])}}. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sir I peak 5 items each time and then call onEndreach prop ...UI stucking and freezing problem minimizes a little bit , not gone properly .... anything to do ?

Comment: Are all the 5 video items automatically playing on the screen? Or are they playing like I suggested in my code? They should be playing if they're visible, that could explain the behavior. Also some libraries have the tendency to function laggy, if the app is in dev mode, therefore you might want to test it in release mode on a real device. Other than that, if the videos are loading from the internet, instead of buffering them at once, wait until they're visible on the screen before buffering, as buffering 5 videos at once might be slow down UI too.

Comment: And would you mind to edit my code accordingly to your functioning code, using react-native-video. This might be helpful for other people, looking for the same approach with react-native-video.